# Azure Data Factory: StartDate in Default Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to specify a default value for startDate parameter as shown below:

[image]

I've been checking how to specify so with functions but so far have I have not find anything.

So far I'm specifying a manual value for startDate, but the idea is to get the current date every time the schedule runs.

I have this defined in a blob storage destination (where it is being used):

```
@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'yyyy')}@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'MM')}@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'dd')}@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'HH')}@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'mm'
```

Is there a way to replace the fact of calling the parameter and use directly utcnow() ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `utcnow()` function, 
or if you will define trigger you can use `trigger().startTime`. 
Other Date functions you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions).

Comment: I'll try it out

Comment: I'm very lost on this, I tried this way: trigger().startTime.utcnow() and I got below error ;

`Activity CopyProd failed: 'In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string 'trigger().startTime.utcnow()' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.`

Answer (score 1):

formatDateTime function you use where you want to return a string in specific date format. 
if the format is not imported for you, and you just want the current date, then you can use `trigger().startTime` or `utcnow()` in expression field. Don't forget @ sign.

trigger().startTime.utcnow is not valid expression.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix this by creating the trigger using a JSON code as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "yourTriggerName",
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "YourPipelineName",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "windowStart": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2018-07-11T17:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        20
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        19
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
And making emphasis of course, in line below:

"parameters": {
                        "windowStart": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
```

After that, the copy activity started to work as expected.